# CAKEPHP 3: Set a value for the default layout. This becomes undefined when fetching content, why?

Tags: cakephp, scope, view, undefined, default

First let me say thanks in advance for your help. I am new to CakePHP framework and I am trying to learn this fast due to a project I’ve been thrown into.

I think my problem might be due to not fully understanding how the views are working. This is how I think it works. (please correct me if I am wrong): The default layout is a template. $this->Fetch() is kind of like ajax where by only the div containing the element is re-rendered/updated?

my basic html default template is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?= $this->Html->charset() ?>
    <?= $this->fetch('meta') ?>
    <?= $this->fetch('css') ?>
    <?= $this->fetch('script') ?>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="top-bar expanded" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area large-3 medium-4 columns">
        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href=""><?= $this->fetch('title') ?></a></h1>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="top-bar-section">
        <?= $this->Element('Navbar/navbar'); ?>
        <?= $this->fetch($navigation); ?>
    </div>
</nav>
<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
<div class="container clearfix">
    <?= $this->fetch('content') ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

in the default layout:

```
<div class="top-bar-section">
    <?= $this->Element('Navbar/navbar'); ?>
    <?= $this->fetch($navigation); ?>
</div>
```

I set the value of $navigation in my UsersController to:

```
   $this->set('navigation', 'navbar2');
```

This calls the element (Element/Navbar/navbar.ctp)

```
<?php $this->start('navbar2'); ?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Session history'), ['controller' => 'Sessions', 'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
</ul>
<?php $this->end(); ?>
```

the result is (web page view):
[navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlZKC.png)
Which is what I wanted.

However, when I click on Session history from /users/home to /sessions this happens:
[undefind var](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN9A6.png)

So either two things are happening, somehow the fetch(‘content’) is causing $navigation to fade out of scope and become undefined or I’m completely wrong about $this-fetch() and what is really happening is the whole default page is reloaded fresh.

I guess my first question is, which one is correct? Ajax style fetch content without refreshing the whole page, or is it refreshed every time and $navigation is a completely new variable that has not been assigned.

In either case, how do I set the default layout values that will only change when an event occurs? In my example, navbar2 is for non-admin, while navbar1 is for admin. I only need to check this once when logging in.

Comment: So after spending the rest of the day looking into it. What worked for me in the end was creating a function in the AppController and calling that function in the initialise function.

The way it seems to be working is, each time a view is rendered the AppController is initialised per view.

If you want some value/behaviour but don't want to add it to every 'beforeRender' function in each Controller, just make the method in AppController and call it inside the initialise function. I have left this open because I'd really like to hear alternative approaches.

Comment: making dynamic navbar  [CakePHP cell](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html) may be the better options

Comment: The way you're using blocks is super-confusing. I recommend you do not do anything like this `<?= $this->fetch($navigation); ?>` and instead either edit your question to only explain what it is you're tring to do (the what, not the how) or delete the question and [get interactive help from the irc/slack channel](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/where-to-get-help.html). `Ajax style fetch content` and `$this->fetch` are not similar at all, `$this->fetch` is [just a mechanism to retrieve an already defined view block](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#view-blocks).